# Can I retrieve the image created with imagepng() after resizing it before storing it in the folder

Tags: php, image, imagecreatefrompng

I have a code that will resize the image to a specific size and store it in a specific folder. until here everything is working fine.
Can I retrieve the image created after resizing it before storing it in the folder, in order to add a watermark to it..
in order to reduce resources as you know...
but My code is giving me an error:
**

> imagecreatefrompng(1): failed to open stream

**

**this my code** :

```
    // resizing code 
     .... 

    $result = imagepng($dst_img);
    

    // i get error : imagecreatefrompng(1): failed to open stream
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($result);
    
        
    $sx = imagesx($im); //get Our PNG Width
    $sy = imagesy($im); //get Our PNG Height


    ......
```

Comment: `imagecreatefrompng()` requires a file, the param is a filename not a png image in memory

Comment: You could try [`imagecopy()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) instead

Comment: Do you mean to use imagecopy() in place of imagecreatefrompng() ?

Comment: I believe I did